# I've done everything that I

Tags: grammar

Which one would sound better and which ones are completely wrong?

I've done everything that I:

> • could, can, have been able to do

Also for this one:
I've been doing everything that I

> • can, have been able to do

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the past] *I did everything I could/was able to do.*

[Up to the present time] *I've done/been doing everything I can. Could* or *was able to do* would work, but *have been able to do* seems rather cumbersome.

Comment: Apart from it being cumbersome, is it incorrect to use it in any way in your opinion?

Comment: Not _incorrect_. just not very idiomatic.